# sonar -> new critical link -> error

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Sonar Version: 4.5.5

Clicking on new critical leads to the following error message:[image]

In the sonar log the following error is reported:

```
2015.10.05 14:45:32 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://sonar.intern/drilldown/measures/39596?metric=new_critical_violations&period=1
    private method `gsub' called for 1:Fixnum
        On line #127 of app/views/drilldown/measures.html.erb

        124:     metric: ''null,
        125:     rule: null,
        126:     severity: null,
        127:     period: null
        128:   };
        129:
        130:

        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb:143:in `escape_javascript'
        app/views/drilldown/measures.html.erb:127
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:346:in `_render_with_layout'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in `render_for_file'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1328:in `default_render'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1334:in `perform_action'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in `call'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
        gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
        gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
        gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
        gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
        gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
        file:/opt/sonarqube-4.5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
        gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
        file:/opt/sonarqube-4.5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
        file:/opt/sonarqube-4.5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
        file:/opt/sonarqube-4.5.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

How can this be fixed? Is this a bug? i tried to post in the sonar google group but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

according to Simon BRANDHOF from sonar source. This is a regression and will be fixed in 4.5.6 (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6814)